# SignalR connecting to existing WebApi Service to get updates

Tags: signalr, asp.net-web-api

Just an outline of what I am trying to do.

I have an existing WebApi service that returns the running windows services on a machine.  I have a front end hooked up so that it querys the service using jQuery and Knockout.js

What I am trying to do with SignalR is to use it to poll the WebAPi service to always push the latest changes to the client.

Is SignalR the right framework for this?

Can someone provide me an example of calling a RESTful service with SignalR?

What i would really like to happen is if a service goes down that SignalR would raise that all the way through the WebApi to the Client.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

SignalR is not the right framework for creating or consuming RESTful services. SignalR is designed to make it easy to push data from the server to the client. REST is designed to support clients making requests and receiving a (near) immediate responses.

You can make requests from a SignalR client to a server-side [Hub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) method, but Hub methods do not expose REST endpoints.